# Ethernet not working after PC start in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-8.1, ethernet, hyper-v

Recently I installed Windows 8.1 x64 on my PC.
Then I enabled Hyper-V in Windows and created a new external virtual switch.
I have the latest LAN driver installed (my ethernet controller is Intel 82579).

**There is a problem with my ethernet.** When I start my PC (eg. in the morning), the ethernet is not working, I have a red cross on the ethernet tray icon. In Device Manager, the device has status:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)
```

In Device Manager, if I "Scan for hardware changes", the problem dissapears.
Or if I restart my PC - the problem also dissapears.

**The problem seems to occur only when I perform a cold-start of my PC.**
Moreover, there's no problem with Windows 8.1 WITHOUT Hyper-V and virtual switch.

I've spent many hours searching the internet for a solution, but all have failed. Can someone help me? It's very frustrating.

**UPDATE**

The problem is also with VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V.

Comment: Try rolling back the driver

Comment: It didn't help. I think the problem is not with the driver.